# python globals dictionary

Tags: global

I want to merge a dictionary , recieved from another module as a function argument to the globals dictionary of the current module. Any idea how this can be done ?

module - test.py

```
def setdict(indict):
    somedict = dict(globals(), **indict)
```

what i want is, the resultant dictionary somedict is to be set as the globals dictionary of the current module (test) . somedict was created by merging globals() of the current module and the recieved dictionary indict.

Comment: *Very* bad idea. `from statically_known_module import *` is bad enough.

Answer (score 4):

`globals()` returns the current module's global dictionary, which you can then modify.  Your function would like:

```
def setdict(indict):
    globals().update(indict)
```

If there are name clashes, the `indict` dictionary will win.