# Assign var in dict loop by content python

Tags: python, getjson

I am passing through some JSON in my script and want to be able to set each key name to its value so that I can call on them individually as variable

Example {'provider': 'Me', 'visitingInformation': None, 'parkingInformation': None, 
'identifier': '123'}

so then I will be able to call each and it resolves to the value

-- >>> provider

-- >>> Me

This is my code so far;

```
def org(cqc):
r = requests.get(url + cqc)
r = (r.json())

a={}

for (key, value) in (r.items()) :
    a[{0}.format(key)] = [{1}.format(value)]
```

currently it is returning back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/Python33/test-files/org-api.py", line 43, in <module>
          org(get_org)
          File "C:/Python33/test-files/org-api.py", line 17, in org
          globals()[{0}.format(key)] = [{1}.format(value)]
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: what issues are you having?

Comment: Why using `globals()[{0}.format(key)] = {1}.format(value)` is bad?

Comment: `a["{0}".format(key)] = ["{0}".format(value)]` maybe what you want  (notice its the `"{0}".format` which is a string, not `{0}.format` which is a set

Comment: but why not just `a[key] = value`

Comment: That returns:     globals()['{0}'.format(key)] = ['{1}'.format(value)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: I agree Daniel ... i was just putting what he had ... I have no idea why he is doing that @Phillip-Marsden ...thats cause you used `{1}` instead of `{0}` ... but really just use DanielRosemans comment

Comment: I have done @DanielRoseman code but it is still returning that the key is not 'defined' so I am still unable to use the key to look at a value dynamically from the json

Comment: here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463378/python-globals-dictionary

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani your solution worked! just had to change the {0} to {:} because I was selecting the first character instead of the item itself (which took me all too long to work out!) - Thanks!

Comment: @Phillip-Marsden Someone down-voted my answer without specifying why :-/

Comment: I think it is because you dared to mention the idea of using global as variables - A lot of people scaremonger the idea of it in python, but in python it is relatively easily managed so I don't really see why.